# Serialize a struct and send it via socket with C++

Tags: c++, sockets, serialization

i would send a struct via C++ sockets. This is an example struct:

```
struct PIPPO
{
int x;
int y;
};
```

that i use with:

```
PIPPO test2;
test2.x = 10;
test2.y = 20;
```

and I have the code above to serialize and send it via socket. The problem is that if I try to get the HEX value of the test variable i only see 0A and infact on the other computer that receives the data I cannot convert back the binary data into a struct. Can someone help me?

```
template <class T> void SerializeData(char *outputArray, T inputData)
{
memcpy(outputArray, &inputData, sizeof(inputData));
}

char *StrToHexStr(char *str)
{
    char *newstr = new char[(strlen(str)*2)+1];
    char *cpold = str;
    char *cpnew = newstr;

    while('\0' != *cpold) {
        sprintf(cpnew, "%02X", (char)(*cpold++));
        cpnew+=2;
    }
    *(cpnew) = '\0';
    return(newstr);
}

char *test = new char[sizeof(PIPPO)];

memcpy((void *)&test, (void *)&test2, sizeof(test2));

send(this->m_socket, test, strlen(test), 0);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sending a raw binary representation over the wire can cause you problem, specially when you have an heterogeneous network or applications. Have a look to [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) which might be best suited for this.

Comment: +1 for providing the link to `protobuf`. it looks interesting. :-)

Comment: I alredy saw google protocol buffer but i think it's really overhead for a program that run on windows and is written in C++ only. I would recommend protobuffer for heterogeneous applications, anyway thank you for the interest in reply to my question

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't really clear, but if your sender and receiver are on the same platform, all you'd need to do is something like the following..

```
PIPPO to_send;
to_send.x = 10;
to_send.y = 20;

// just send the structure
send(this->m_socket, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&to_send), sizeof(to_send), 0);
```

on the receiver side..

```
PIPPO to_receive;
// now read directly into the structure
recv(this->m_socket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&to_receive), sizeof(to_receive));
```

This approach should work fine as long as same platform, if you don't care about backward compatibility of protocols etc.

Comment: Ive spent a few days trying to do this cleanly, and you helped me solve it. People really overcomplicate things, don't they

Comment: @Charlie, yes they do... anyway - will edit the above, it can be even simpler... :)

Answer (score 1):

for sending textual representation you could use [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) library.
It is well documented and supports features like:
1. (de)serialization of contianers
2. (de)serialization of tree of objects
3. Pointers to objects (de)serialization
4. Polimorphic (de)serialization
5. Full typesafety
and many more..

Actually, I think there's some black magic generator inside :)

Regards,
Marcin

Comment: i tought the same thing, but i saw that boost serialization library doesn't have support for big/little endian. Is this right?

Comment: Textual archives are portable but binary are not: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/archives.html#archive_models   So If you really require binary representation it will require some workarounds (maybe implementing/finding a "portable stream" for the archive).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it raises a lot of alignment and bytes order issues.
The way to go is to use [XDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) or actually switch to text representation.
All the ways, it's useless to encode your binary into hex.